# RCX 1.0 downloaded firmware successfully with RIS 2.0 but does not run any program

Tags: rcx

I have installed correctly the RIS 2.0 in an old laptop running Windows XP and I successfully downloaded the firmware through the RIS 2.0 to the RCX 1.0, following the standard setup instructions.

Now when I turn on my RCX 1.0, the display shows the full function mode. I can also change the activated sensor port and the outputs pressing the View button. Yet, the Prgm and Run button do nothing.

I cannot change or run any program. It stays in program 1, which does not run when I press the run button.

I would appreciate any help please.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a hardware problem. Do you by any chance have access to a RCX remote (or NXT with IRLink) to see if you can run programs that way? Can you actually download programs without trouble? (I'm not sure anymore if the standard RIS interface allows to start a program remotely, but if it does, you should try it too)

Comment: Are you sure rcx 1.0 works with firmware 2.0?

Comment: Simple solution: ensure that the RCX is connected to your computer and that they are both updated to the latest version. if this doesn't work, downgrade the firmware to the previous versions if you already had the RCX before updating.